# OpenVPN multihop over tun0 device between two servers

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

**What I have is**

`A` in my region, and `B` in another region (both servers are CentOS 7).

**The reason of this question is**

I can connect from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `A`, but the final goal is to have internet via `B`, because it has limitless internet (by limitless I mean no 403 errors).

**I'm thinking of this**

- create connection from `B` to `A`, then I connect to OpenVPN in `A`
  and `A` sends the packets and grants me a limitless internet over
  `tun0` device to `B`.

**What I am trying to achieve**

1. create a `tun0` device in `A` with subnet `10.8.0.1/24` (which is done so far by this [link](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install)), and create another `tun0` device in `B` with subnet `10.9.0.1/24` (it doesn't matter if it should be in the same subnet of `A`.
2. then connect these two `tun` devices via `ssh` (I think they should be able to ping each other private IPs with command line `ping -c1 -I tun0 10.8.0.2`) (in this case, `B` should connect to `A`).
3. Add an `iptables masquerade` rule in both servers, so they can mask.
4. Finally,

**What I think should be done**

1. Create a persistent connection from `B` to `A` and `A` to `B` via `tun0` device (I googled but didn't find good results).
2. Running these two commands in both servers (both main interfaces are `eth0` (I think I'm missing something here):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

3. If other configurations should be done that I don't know, they're here I believe.
4. Then I should change the final `OpenVPN`'s client config file like this (from the server trying to connect to another one):

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote A Port
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
...
```

**What I have done so far**

1. Installed OpenVPN via given [link](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) in `A`
2. Added new `tun0` device in `B`:

```
ip addr add 10.9.0.1/24 dev tun0
```

3. Ran the `masquerade` in both servers:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

4. Enable `ipv4.forwarding` in both servers and disabled firewall in both servers to be sure that wouldn't cause any problems.

Can you help me how can I do this scenario and have a multihop OpenVPN for myself?

Comment: You don't need to masquerade on both servers. Only the "B" system where packets exit to Internet needs masquerading on its "wan" interface. Also, NAT *is* performed by the firewall, so you can't entirely disable it while doing masquerading. Only the "B" server which actually forward packets need forwarding enabled; "A" doesn't do any forwarding.  And, you need to make sure that after tunnel is established "A" has a direct route towards "B" and the default gateway is set to the "B"'s tunnel IP address. // I explained this kind of setup *several tims* on various SE sites, please search better.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thanks, I saw your answers on `SuperUser` and `ServerFault` both, but couldn't find any question title relating to what I want. Can you help me which question it was to see your answer.